# Access records created by CRM users in D365 Portals

Tags: dynamics-crm-online

As I understand, we can access records created by Portal users and their respective Entity Permissions apply for them. However, I wanted those users to be able to even access records which were created by CRM users within Dynamics 365 (and not records created from Portal by a Portal user which is assigned to System)

Is this possible? If yes, how can I achieve that?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It does not matter who created the record, what matters is if that user has access to it. It would not make much sense to show only records that were created by the portal users - how would you then handle something like Customer Service (on one end users use portal, but on the other they are using CRM, bot are creating records).
So basically I'm not sure how aware are you of the configuration of permissions, but let's say that you configured that a Contact (which is a portal user) has access to all records "Cases" that are referencing this contact (this is simply configuration in Entity Permission record). If yes then contact will see records created by him and all other cases that are referencing him as a contact, so if you as a CRM user will create a Case for a Contact, this Contact will see the case.